# Determine whether $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( 1-\frac{1}{2n} \right)^{\alpha n \ln(n)}$ converge or diverge for different $\alpha$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> How can we show whether the series converges or diverges for different $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$:
>
> $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( 1-\frac{1}{2n} \right)^{\alpha n \ln(n)} $$

I tried to use the limit comparison test, and also after using *WolframAlpha* it seems like the series converges only for $\alpha > 2$.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Comment: Try using $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1 - \tfrac1{x}\right)^{x} \to e^{-1}$ along with the continuity of $e^x$ to design a direct comparison.  This should let you resolve the question for all but possibly $\alpha = 2$.

Comment: Why would it fail for alpha being 2 ? think about it. and about the limit of the summands.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution finally:
First we can write $(1-\frac{1}{2n})^{\alpha \cdot nlogn}=
e^{\alpha \cdot nlogn \cdot log(1-\frac{1}{2n})}$
and then, by using a comparison test with $e^{-\frac{a}{2}\cdot logn}$
I got that the series converges only for $\alpha>2$.
The intuition came by using the Taylor expansion of $log(1-\frac{1}{2n})$ in the second term